# My personal Google account has policies enforced that I can't figure out how to change

Tags: google-chrome

My personal Google account has 3 policies, (most annoyingly, `BrowserAddPersonEnabled == false`) that I would like to change, but I can't figure out how.

My account is not managed by any organization, and as far as I can tell is not linked to any other accounts. These policies are also present on the other accounts on my Mac.

I do not know when these policies changed, but I do know they were not always this way.

Noting that I am not a Windows user, does anyone know how I can change these back to default?

Comment: have you tried googling the policy name?

Comment: Yes, but there was not very much information on how to change things back to default, only suggestions for ways for companies to manage their employees' accounts.